# Keyboard input detection

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and would like to know whether it can be used to detect keyboard inputs entered by the user.

I am planning to write a software that will be platform independent, and this software should be able to get all User inputs on the hardware/software keyboard.

Is this possible using OpenCV?

Thanks!

Comment: which programming lang?

Comment: C++ using Visual Studio 2012 IDE

Comment: what do you mean platform independent? Visual Studio 2012 can compile for Windows only

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "software keyboard" but you can detect keypress in OpenCV using [cv::waitKey](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#cv.WaitKey)..

HTH

Comment: I mean on-screen keyboard, like in mobile devices.

Comment: You should specify that in the question. There is no tag nor any mention of a mobile device. That just earns you a vote-down. As for your answer, you can do that using the SDK of the respective mobile platform.